# Преобразовать одноуровневый список во вложенный lisp

Tags: lisp

Помогите преобразовать пожалуйста

```
(defun F (L M)
    (cond 
        ((null L) M)
        ((F (cdr L) (list M (car L))))))
```

по идее должно быть вот так : (a s d f g) –> (((((a) s) d) f) g)

set и setq нельзя использовать

в коде выше нужно убрать только "NIL"

Comment: вывод моей программы - (((((NIL A) S) D) F) G)

Comment: как ты вызываешь эту функцию?

Comment: (f’(a s d f g) ‘())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что на первой итерации `M` еще пустой список, и при применении к нему функции `list` получается `(() a)`.

Для решения можно просто проверить, что `M` пустой список и если это так - использовать либо не использовать `M`, либо использовать `cons` вместо `list`, например:

```
(defun F (L M)
    (cond 
        ((null L) M)
        ((null M) (F (cdr L) (cons (car l) M)))
        ((F (cdr L) (List M (car l)) ))))
```

Либо

```
(defun F (L M)
    (cond 
        ((null L) M)
        ((null M) (F (cdr L) (list (car l))))
        ((F (cdr L) (List M (car l)) ))))
```